# Converting Date in workweek in excel vba

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

Hi I am having a columns in which dates are present in yyyy-mm-dd h:mm:ss format. 
I want to convert them into workweeks.

I tried it like

```
For DateCounter = 1 To UBound(All_Submitted_Dates)
    All_workweek(DateCounter) = WorksheetFunction.WeekNum(All_Submitted_Dates(DateCounter))
Next DateCounter
```

But I am getting subscript out of range exception. Can anybody tell me whats the error?

Comment: How did you declare the arrays and the submitted_dates how did you fill them? We need more info to help you

Comment: I assigned it directly. All_Submitted_Dates = Range("K2", Range("K1").End(xlDown))

Comment: Have you considered =WEEKNUM(A1) ? gives the week number directly from the date... assumed that A1 contains the date...

Comment: yes. If I am using weeknum function directly from excel i am getting proper output.

Comment: Use the debugger in step by step mode and try to see if the array is 0 index based. Does the error happens in the last range’s item?

Comment: Have you tried `All_Submitted_Dates(DateCounter,1)`?

Comment: @RicardoDiaz Array index is starting from 1.

Comment: @FoxfireAndBurnsAndBurns Yes I have tried it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assigning an array from a range directly ends up resulting in a `2D` array and not a `1D`. To overcome this you can either reference it as such e.g. `All_Submitted_Dates(DateCounter, 1)` or `Transpose` your input.

If your input data is kept in a single column you just need to `Transpose` it once

```
With Application
    All_Submitted_Dates = .Transpose(Range("K2", Range("K1").End(xlDown)))
End With
```

However, if your data is in multiple columns you will need to double `Transpose` it to get the `1D` array

```
With Application
    All_Submitted_Dates = .Transpose(.Transpose(Range("K2", Range("K1").End(xlDown))))
End With
```

You can then reference your array as you have done in the rest of your code

***Update after comments***
I think your issue is due to a combination of things (however this may just be due to your haven't included the information in your question). Can you take a look at the code below.

I've declared both `All_Submitted_Dates` and `All_WorkWeek` as variants. I've then set the `All_Submitted_Dates` with an explicit sheet reference (Yours would have been taking from the `ActiveSheet` possibly causing errors) and also `Transpos[e]`ing the values so that the code is working with a `1D` array. I've then `ReDim`ed the `All_WorkWeek` array so that the size matches with `All_Submitted_Dates`. I've then used your `For` loop as you've written above. However, I would suggest to use `Lbound(All_Submitted_Dates)` instead of 1 although it shouldn't matter too much but is good practice.

You will need to update the `With Sheet1` block with a reference to your sheet where your input Data is stored however, this in my tests, works as intended.

```
Dim All_Submitted_Dates As Variant, All_WorkWeek As Variant
Dim DateCounter As Long
' Update with your sheet reference
With Sheet1
    All_Submitted_Dates = Application.Transpose(.Range(.Range("K2"), .Cells(.Rows.Count, "K").End(xlUp)))
End With

ReDim All_WorkWeek(LBound(All_Submitted_Dates) To UBound(All_Submitted_Dates))
For DateCounter = 1 To UBound(All_Submitted_Dates)
    All_WorkWeek(DateCounter) = WorksheetFunction.WeekNum(All_Submitted_Dates(DateCounter))
Next DateCounter
```

The issues I found where:

- Array being declared as `2D` and referenced as `1D`
- Weak Range references meaning code was referring to `ActiveSheet` possibly causing errors
- Range selection using `End(xlDown)` but starting above the first cell, causing the Range to only select one cell (therefore possibly defaulting to value of cell rather than creating an array)
- `All_WorkWeek` possibly not initiated correctly so that it wouldn't accept any values

Comment: I have tried it as All_Submitted_Dates(DateCounter, 1). But I am getting the same error.

Comment: and have you tried transposing it as above? Are you sure your array is populated?

Comment: @NAVEENPRAKASH Take a look at my update. I've had a further look at your code